How to deal with ambiguous powershell commands with same names but coming from 2 different modules
The same command "Get-VM" can come either from module HyperV or module PowerCLI (VMWare)
How to distinguish them when calling them?

Use a module-qualified name:
[ModuleName]\[Cmdlet_or_Function_Name]

